# looking for a hosted back-end business data storage for analytics

Tags: google-visualization, google-fusion-tables, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

i want a simple hosted data store for licensed for business applications.  i want the following features:

- REST-like access for CRUD operations (primarily adding records)
- private and authenticated
- makes for easy integration with a front end charting client like Google Visualization Apis
- easy to use and set up

what about:
* Google Fusion Tables
* Google Cloud Services
* Google BigQuery
* Google Cloud SQL

or other non-google products.  but i am imagining a cleaner integration between Google Charts and one of their backend data services.

Pros, Cons, Advice?

Answer (score 0):

First, since this is Stack Overflow, I won't attempt to provide a judgement about how about "easy to use and setup" - that can be done by you reading the documentation for each product.

That being said, overall, the "right" answer really depends on what you are trying to do, and how much data you have. It also depends on what type of application you are building (this is Stack Overflow, so I am assuming you are a developer).

Relational Databases (like Google Cloud SQL) are great for maintaining transactional consistency but once your data grows massive it becomes difficult, expensive, or impossible to run analysis queries in a reasonable timeframe.

Google BigQuery is an analysis tool that allows developers to ask questions about really really big datasets using an SQL like language. It is 100% cloud based and is accessed via RESTful API - but it only allows for appending data, not changing individual records.